How to handle two-step login with Jsoup in an Android app for scraping data?
I'm developing an Android app where I need to scrape data from my university's UIMS (University Information Management System) using Jsoup.
The login process involves two steps

On the first page, I need to enter my UID and click the "Next"
button.

On the second page, I need to enter my password and solve a captcha
before logging in.


Here’s the issue I’m facing:
When I try to handle this two-step login process with Jsoup, the response I get is always the HTML        content of the first page (where only the UID is entered). It never navigates to the second page   where the password and captcha are required.`
this is first page 
this is second image
site url

Without looking at the source, I would guess that it is a SPA, a Single Page Application, and the "second page" is really not loaded / navigated to, but rather displayed using a combination of JavaScript and AJAX. You will either have to simulate that, or find the AJAX calls it makes in your browser's Dev Tools and perform them directly from your code.
